# Check if current process can write N bytes of data to a memory address?

Tags: pointers, memory, out-of-memory

I was solving some general computer science problems and I came across this question.

How would you implement a function bool isMemoryWritable(void *p, size_t n) that checks if the current process could write N bytes to the given memory address? Assume you can catch any kind of error.

I didn't quite get what the question tries to ask. There are 2 interpretations that I can think of a) Check if there is enough memory available starting from the given address such that N bytes can be accommodated. b) Check whether or not some other data is already present within N bytes from the given address.

It would be great if someone could explain what the question asks exactly and how can we go about solving it.

Comment: Probably just looking for a try/catch where you try to write n bytes at the dest address and then if you catch an exception you know it's not writeable.

Comment: Bad question. It assumes memory is or isn't writable. In reality, there's memory which can be _made_ writable. (Lazy alloc on page fault). Next, it fails to state if the test may be destructive. If not, you need an atomic read-don't-modify-write.